# Reverse order of legend in graph with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following graph

[image]

and I want to reverse the order of the legend so the first one that is shown at the top is category 10 and at the bottom is category 1. (I want to do this with VBA)

Edit: I found a code that works but it also changes the order of the values on the chart so it does not work, I don't know if it's possible to just change the order of the values within the legend.

Comment: Did you already try to use the macro recorder while doing this manually?

Comment: @BigBen I found a piece of code that reverses them 
the issue with this is that it also changes the order of the values within the area chart. I wanted to know if there is a way to only change the order of the legend itself.

Comment: [Here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_winother-mso_2010/can-i-reverse-series-order-in-a-chart-legend/e7c9527a-cc9a-485d-86af-1ebf7fd50c01) is an approach you may be able to use. Not sure it'll work with a 3D chart though.

Comment: @BigBen I was looking at this earlier but it doesn't work with a 3D area chart because if you delete a legend that has 0 as value then it will disappear from the legend but not from the chart and I will get extra categories in the chart itself that I don't need. I thought about changing the names of the legends manually but then the colours won't match that way.

Comment: Yeah. This might not be doable with a 3D chart then. (Time to ditch Excel and use something else, e.g. Python and matplotlib).